# 'Show More' & 'Show Less' with jQuery for an article website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I am trying to show an extra row of articles when user clicks 'show more' and I want to remove that row with 'show less'.

I have 4 rows of articles, but I want to start with 2 rows and have the user add one row at a time.
My jQuery might be a little messed up because I took bits and pieces from different places.
I simplified the code by removing the content.

Any idea why it's not working?

```
<div class="writing-clips">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Writing Clips</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-1" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-2">
      <a href="#">
        content
      </a>
    </div>           
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container clips-2 li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-5" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-6" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content     
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container clips-3 li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-9" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-10" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content   
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container clips-4 li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-13" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-14" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
<div class="showmore">showmore</div>
<div class="showless">showless</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  size_li = $(".writing-clips .li").size();
  x=2;
  $('.writing-clips .li:lt('+x+')').show();
  $('.showmore').click(function () {
    x= (x+1 <= size_li) ? x+1 : size_li;
    $('.writing-clips .li:lt('+x+')').show();
  });
  $('.showless').click(function () {
    x=(x-1<2) ? 2 : x-1;
    $('.writing-clips .li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
  });

});
```

css:

```
.writing-clips .li { display: none; }

.showmore {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: green;
}

.showmore:hover { color: blue; }

.showless {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

.showless:hover { color: blue; }

Comment: does this work like you expect it to? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWLyOP

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide all rows before show first two

Add this line

```
$('.writing-clips .li').hide();
```

before

```
$('.writing-clips .li:lt('+x+')').show();
```

Comment: sorry, I did not include the CSS. It already had a display: none;

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written your script...

The this is to perform the correct comparison and increment a counter which represent how many are actually shown.

See console logs and comments in code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // Show first four.
  var shownOnload = 4;
  for(i=0;i<shownOnload;i++){
    $(".col").eq(i).show();
  }
  
  // Total link we have
  var size_li = $(".col").length;
  console.log( " Total: " +size_li );

  // More handler
  $(".showmore").click(function () {
    console.log("More clicked!");
    
    if(shownOnload<size_li && shownOnload>=0){
      shownOnload++;
      console.log("Show #"+shownOnload);
      $(".col").eq(shownOnload-1).show();
    }
  });
  
  // Less handler
  $(".showless").click(function () {
    console.log("Less clicked!");
    
    if(shownOnload<=size_li && shownOnload>0){
      console.log("Hide #"+shownOnload);
      $(".col").eq(shownOnload-1).hide();
      shownOnload--;
    }
  });

}); // ready
```

```css
.col{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="writing-clips">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Writing Clips</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-1" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-2">
      <a href="#">
        content 2
      </a>
    </div>           
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container clips-2 li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-5" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 3
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-6" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 4
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container clips-3 li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-9" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 5
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-10" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 6
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clip-container clips-4 li">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-13" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 7
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box" id="story-14" href="#">
      <a href="#">
        content 8
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
<div class="showmore">showmore</div>
<div class="showless">showless</div>
```